# OS X WebKit possible to recieve connection speed?

Tags: objective-c, webkit

I am workin on a small internet browser in Xcode for OS X using the WebKit framework and I was wondering if it was possible to get a WKWebView's live connection speeds (Upload and Download) to the website and display them in Level Indicators (and write values next to them in textfields). (or any alternatives if not possible with WebKit) Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

To determine the actual speed, you need to measure the time it takes to upload or download a buffer of known length. If you just need to know if they're connected via WiFi or some other (presumably slower) method, there are ways to determine the type of connection you have. Here's a random example I found for doing this: [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-macos)